# .Net Enterprise Cache - refresh instantly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-cache, asp.net-caching

I'm using Enterprise Library Caching for my MVC3 application.

My code is something like this:

```
object myLock = new Object();

public static MyEntity[] getMyEntities()
        {
            MyEntity[] res;

            res = getMyEntities(new GetMyEntitiesRefreshAction());
            return res;
        }

        private class GetMyEntitiesRefreshAction : ICacheItemRefreshAction
        {
            public void Refresh(string removedKey, object expiredValue, CacheItemRemovedReason removalReason)
            {
                getMyEntitiesInCache(this);
            }
        }

        private static MyEntity[] getMyEntitiesInCache(ICacheItemRefreshAction action)
        {
            ICacheManager defaultCache = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ICacheManager>();
            MyEntity[] result;

            lock (myLock)
            {
                if ((result = defaultCache.GetData("myEntities") as MyEntity[]) == null)
                {
                    using (EntityContext _entities = new EntityContext())
                    {
                        res = _entities.MyEntity
                            .Include("A.B.C")
                            .Include("A.B.D")
                            .Include("A.B.E")
                            .Include("A.B.F.G")
                            .Include("A.B.H.I.J")
                            .Include("A.B.K.L")
                            .Include("A.B.K.M")
                            .Include("A.B.N.O")
                            .Where(x => x.Active && x.Type == 1).ToArray();
                            //this query takes 20 seconds or more
                    }

                    defaultCache.Add("myEntities", result, CacheItemPriority.High, action, new AbsoluteTime(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

So, when someone calls getMyEntities, and elements are cached, there's no problem. But when elements are expired or are being loaded into the cache, users have to wait a long time before they see some results.
Is there a way to always return something INSTANTLY? If I'm executing the query I would like to return the expired object so that users don't have to wait, and when query completes, I would just keep the new results.
Any ideas?